# Generate classes from xsd files in a Maven project

Tags: spring, web-services, maven, xsd

I created a maven project put the xsd files
Then I run :

`mvn clean package`

what was generated was only two empty directories :

> target
>
> -- generated-sources
>
> ---- annotations
>
> ---- test-annotations

I am using this plugin from a tutorial :

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>

     <executions>
      <execution>
       <goals>
        <goal>xjc</goal>
       </goals>
      </execution>
     </executions>
     <configuration>
      <schemaDirectory>src/main/webapp/schemas/</schemaDirectory>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it,
I have to run this command line :

mvn -X clean jaxb2:xjc

instead of

mvn clean package

Thanks